# Remove the category title which appears on category page in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to remove category title on the page where I am displaying static blocks. I have created static blocks and selecting a block for a category in admin. At the front end I am seeing category title. I want to hide the category title. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

@AshwaniPanwar I wouldn't recommend getting rid of the title all completely. It's wrapped in a H1, and you don't want an empty H1 laying on your page (or no H1 at all). Hide it with CSS is by far the best solution for *your* problem

Answer (score 1):

open below file `\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`

and comment  `<h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>` near about line 47.

hope this help you